# Should I update to Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: drivers, updates, graphics, games, radeon

Should I update to the new (2016/8/15 date today) 16.04LTS Ubuntu? I have a PC what has these specs:

-AMD A8-7600 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G
-16 GB RAM

Now, why am I curious?
Because I heard that Linux is running bad if I want to use it for professional graphic usage, or gaming. I don't know if the drivers will perform good with my specs, as like it did on Windows, I heard many Linux users to avoid my Linux with my AMD build. I really want to use Linux, while I'm making my game on the Unity engine. So AMD users, what do you suggest 16.04LTS or should I install Windows and make my game on that?

By the way, the only thing why I'm not using Windows is because there are many MANY BSoD's.

If you have your suggestion just leave a comment that what should I install.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you game and do a lot of graphical tasks, it's not a good idea to upgrade.

16.04 (and any version of Linux using the latest Xorg version) doesn't support `fglrx`, the proprietary AMD graphics driver for Linux. There are open source drivers, but they don't provide the same performance.

Now, people have reported both ends of performance, good and bad, with the open source drivers on 16.04, but for intense gaming, performance won't be great. There is the new [AMDGPU-PRO driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx), which does support 16.04, but, as you can see on that page, it doesn't have much compatibility, and it isn't compatible with your card.

So, in regards to graphical performance under intense situations (Unity game development counts I think), no, you should not upgrade to 16.04, at least if you want to continue developing without issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Windows and Linux Ubuntu 14.04 AND Linux Ubuntu 16.04 on separate partitions. When you turn on your computer a menu will appear letting you pick which operating system to boot. Furthermore under advanced options you can pick the kernel version that is loaded for Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04.

As a new game developer you'll want to look at the new Vulkan graphcis subsystem under Linux and new DirectX 12 under Windows 10.

As far as Windows BSoD's goes... most users don't have them. If they do they should find out the root cause (drivers, registry glitches, etc) and fix them. Personally I'll buy a Windows 10 laptop with 4k screen that costs $2k today for $400 a couple of years from now and install Linux on it using dual boot.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm making my game under DX9-DX11, I don't want to make a game what I can't make properly. :)

Comment: It takes years to make a game by yourself. I would suggest doing it on new platforms not old ones. Also things like FrostBite offer free programming language until you sell a whole bunch of games I believe. Sorry I don't know much. Picked up a C graphics programming book when I was 20ish, got a headache and stuck to information programming ever since then.